# phpunit test assertNotRegExp() not working as expected?

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit, lumen

Test failed asserting that '{"error":{"message":"Book not found"}}' does not match PCRE pattern "/Book not found/".

**Why is this pattern not matching the content string?**

```
<?php

namespace Tests\App\Http\Controllers;

use TestCase;

class BooksControllerTest extends TestCase
{
    /** @test **/
    public function show_route_should_not_match_an_invalid_route()
    {
        $this->get('/books/this-is-invalid');

        $this->assertNotRegExp(
            '/Book not found/',
            $this->response->getContent(),
            'BooksController@show route matching when it should not.'
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The pattern `/Book not found/` **does** match the content string `{"error":{"message":"Book not found"}}`. That works correctly.

Note that you're using `assertNotRegExp()` - i.e. you're literally saying - "Make sure that the pattern **does not** match the string". So the assertion succeeds when the pattern does not match, and fails when the pattern matches.

Seems like you actually wanted to use `assertRegExp()` for your test.

Comment: Hmmm. Working through "Writing API's with Lumen." I found I misread a section about updating the route. Fixed the duplicate route with $app->get('/books/{id:[\d]+}', 'BooksController@show'); and now test works. Route does not match that expression it will not be routed to the controller.